# What is the scope of casted variable in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, casting, scope, variable-assignment

When casting a variable at the right side of the assign, i'm surprisely realize that the variable still behave as the casted type and not as it was original defined.
Am i doing something wrong or it's a compiler issue?

Code:

```
val hippoList = listOf<Hippo>(Hippo())
val hippoMutableList : MutableList<Hippo> = hippoList as MutableList<Hippo>
hippoList.add(Hippo())
```

since *hippoList* is from a *List* type, it is immutable. So how does trying to run *add* function on an immutable type isn't cause to compilation error?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing casting it means that you know more than a compiler about this context of execution and you're telling the compiler that this hippoList is a MutableList so on every next usage of hippoList compiler already knows that this have to be a MutableList and allows you to use `add` method because you casted it  to MutableList previously. In fact you will get a runtime error `UnsupportedOperationException` which means that you didn't really know more about this context of execution and you did something wrong. So instead of using casting on your own allow compiler to do it's work.

In your case instead of a casting to MutableList, transform hippoList to MutableList with
`hippoList.toMutableList()`

The same happens when you're using `!!` from nullable type to not null type, when you're using it when you know more than a compiler about the context of execution. Here's a little example

```
val someNullableType: String? = null
val thisStringIsNotNull = someNullableType!!
```

by using !! on someNullableType we're telling the compiler that someNullableType is not null as well, so we're allowed to write (as in you're case where you're telling that your List is a MutableList as well)

```
someNullableType.length
```

but we will receive exception earlier (in place where we used !! to tweak the compiler)

Comment: @laughter, thanks for the answer but i have some issues with the answer: 1. In java casting doesn't affect the variable in the right side of assignment statement. 2. I prefer casting because i didn't want a copy of the list, i want the same list so changes in one place will affect the other.  3. Can you please show an example what you meant with !! because it isn't so clear. thanks!

Comment: @SiddharthSharma please run this code, and you will see that you're allowed to cast List to MutableList

Comment: @laughter, i have run and the exception is really *UnsupportedOperationException *

Comment: @Eitanos30 i've added more explanation to the !! usage and how it affects the compiler

Comment: @Eitanos30 > In java casting doesn't affect the variable in the right side of assignment statement.
As you can see kotlin compiler is a little smarter, and if you're doing something to tweak this and you're doing it wrong you can get a runtime error, so try to never use casting if you're not sure, let the compiler to do the work

Comment: thanks for the explanation!!! but i don't think kotlin compiler is smarter. I think Kotlin put all their effort to make Kotlin different from java & many other convenient  language, and many times it makes thing unclear or bad. my opinion :)

Comment: > 2 I prefer casting because i didn't want a copy of the list, i want the same list so changes in one place will affect the other.
So in fact you need to use MutableList type and mutableListOf() then you can be sure that you're using one list and you're not copying the list

Comment: *mutableListOf* function returns a copy of the list and not the original one

Comment: I mean use the mutableListOf from top to bottom i you don't want to copy your lists
val hippoList = mutableList(Hippo())
hippoList.add(Hippo())

Comment: @laugher it is really an  options :)